# Will low memory prevent a modal view controller from being displayed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view controller that I would like to present in a modal fashion, but it will not appear.  I think it's because whilst in the Image Picker I see this in the console:

```
2010-12-06 22:44:28.076 AppName[2084:307] Received memory warning. Level=1
2010-12-06 22:45:09.047 AppName[2084:307] Received memory warning. Level=2
2010-12-06 22:44:09.234 AppName[2084:307] Received memory warning. Level=1
```

Does low or using large memory allocations prevent modal view controllers from being presented?

Also - its noteworthy to say that this modal view controller is being presented from another modal view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer : NO !.

When memory warning are not handled and memory become so low that memory allocation failed, the application crashes. Memory Warning Level 2 is really really close to that point.